Does Ubuntu Unity Have an App That's the Equivelent of KDE's Device Notifier? Or Do I Have to Use Nautilus?
Is there an app that can be installed in the side panel of Ubuntu Unity 24.04 that manages external USB drives like the KDE app Device Notifier? Or do I have to open Files? Thanks in advance.
